# Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"my-app"}

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli-v7

I have newly installed angular 7. But I am not able to create new project. I have done all which I could find from the internet but none works. I have also mentioned commands which I have used. Any help would be appreciated.

Initial command

`$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

Error I got

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"my-
app"}
Errors:

  Data path "" should have required property 'version'.
```

My system information

```
$ npm -v //6.9.0
$ node -v //v8.9.4
$ ng --version  // Angular CLI: 7.3.8
```

**Solutions I tried**

First method

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli (add sudo in the start if using Linux)
npm cache clean --force / npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Second

```
ng new myApp //does not worlk
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Yeah right. I have also tried them. I think there is a version issue with new angular.

Comment: check if you has no any .json in the directory you try `ng new`.

Comment: Yeah but project directory is not yet present. `ng new my-app` is giving error at first.